# Would questions about installing Linux on the Gemini PDA be more appropriate on Unix or SuperUser?

Tags: discussion, scope

Site members may be aware of the new (as at 2018) [Gemini PDA](https://www.planetcom.co.uk/), a keyboarded clamshell device which runs Android by default, but which can also run Linux (a Debian install image is available), Sailfish OS (porting under development), and possibly also others.

Would questions about installing Linux on this device be more appropriate here on Unix.SE or perhaps on SuperUser instead (as questions are perhaps more likely to relate more to help with support for and installing on this specific hardware, rather than how to do everyday tasks as on any other Linux system (once installed)?

Comment: I don't have time to post an answer now (I'll try to tomorrow) but at first glance, I'd say here is more likely than SU. I'm not even 100% sure it would be on topic on SU (it might be, I'm just not sure).

Answer (score 4):

I talked it over with a Super User moderator, and the consensus was that the Gemini would likely be off topic on SU. On the other hand, we cover *nix systems, irrespective of hardware, so your questions would be on topic here.

However, I can't promise we'll be much help if the issues are hardware specific. Always worth a shot though, so go for it!